# Start foundation js in Ember (using ember-cli)

Tags: ember.js, zurb-foundation

In my project I am trying to use Foundation's accordion but to no avail. Specifically I have followed this guide here https://coderwall.com/p/azjwaq but it doesn't work. It only works if I explicitly refresh the page, but If I navigate to another controller it stops working. Is this the correct way to initialize foundation 5?
I use foundation 5.3.3 with ember 1.8.0-beta1 and ember-cli 0.44.

Edit:
heads up! I managed to make it work. BUT the whole app now is really really *really* slow. Specifically I have this inititializer in app/initializer/foundation.js.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default {
  name: 'foundation-config',
  initialize: function() {
    Ember.View.reopen({
      startFoundation: function() {
        Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function(){
          $(document).foundation();
        });
      }.on('didInsertElement')
    });
  }
};
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this:

Stop initializing Foundation for each view. Try extending views which contain accordion to a separate object and then extend it.

```
App.FoundationView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function () {
        $(document).foundation();
    }
});

App.ViewWhichNeedFoundation = App.FoundationView.extend({
    ...
})
```

Answer (score -2):

Simply initializing foundation the normal way manually worked for me.  Just before the closing body tag:

```
    
    <script>
    $(document).foundation();
    </script>
```